# Retain keyword not throwing compiler error in Xcode 4.6 ARC project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I just started a new contract on-site at a client.

I'm starting work on an app prototype written by an Android developer who was new to Objective-C. (He has since left the company, so he's not available to ask questions.)

The project is written in Objective-C using ARC. One of the files has properties declared as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) <class> *<name>;
```

(where `<class>` and `<name>` are replaced with the actual class and property name of each property.)

In the past, when I've tried to include manual reference counted code in an ARC project the compiler has thrown an error on the `retain` keyword. In this project, however, it's not complaining.

I checked, and the file is not set to compile with manual reference counting.

I edited the property definitions and replaced the word `retain` with `strong`, and that compiles also.

Has Apple recently changed the compiler so that `retain` is a synonym for `strong` in ARC? And conversely, is `strong` a synonym for `retain` in a file that's compiled with manual reference counting?

If so, when was this change made?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) <class> *<name>; works great at ARC projects... there is an error at another place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not particularly well documented, but this [ARC transitioning doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) states:

```
// The following declaration is a synonym for: @property(retain) MyClass *myObject;
@property(strong) MyClass *myObject;
```

Note the word *synonym*, which implies both `retain` and `strong` attributes mean the same thing.

Comment: I have a strong, if vague, memory, of getting compiler errors when mixing code that used different memory management semantics (ARC code in manual reference counted apps, or visa-versa.) What am I thinking of, then? Is it the `__strong` and `__retain` qualifiers on instance variables? I'm confused...

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it.

Answer (score 1):

From the document Clang 3.8 documentation [Property declarations](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations) section:

> retain implies __strong ownership.

As far as I remember `retain` has always been synonym for `strong` in a property statement.

This is just a keyword in the property statement, there is no reason to imply that this carries over as a general equivalent between the two in other usages. What it did is make conversion from pre-ARC to ARC somewhat easier.